# hg: merging a single changeset and not the whole tree

Tags: mercurial, merge

Let's say I have anonymous branches AA and BB.

In branch AA there is a changeset CC which I'd like to merge into BB, without bringing in all its parents.

Doing this would work:

```
hg diff -c CC >>CC.diff
patch -p1 <CC.diff
```

However, I'd lose the information that this the same changeset as CC, I'd just be creating a new one which happens to do the same thing.

Is there a more repository-friendly way to go?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can cherrypick changesets using the [`hg transplant`](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/TransplantExtension) extension.

`transplant` is fine when you cannot do a full merge for some reason. However, it is [not recommended](http://kiln.stackexchange.com/questions/3465/integrated-transplant/3466#3466) to rely on it in your daily workflow due to its side effects.

**EDIT:** This functionality is a core feature (`hg graft`) in Mercurial since version 2.0.

Comment: Apparently what `transplant` did now is more or less done by the native `graft` since Mercurial 2.0. (I tried to include it in the answer, since that's what I actually ended up using, but no, for whatever reasons the edit was discarded [gg])

Comment: @Lohoris, good point for the future. I added that to my answer.